# Download the Media (mp3) presented by the UIWebView in fullscreen

Tags: ios, uiwebview, download, mp3, media

So I am working on a piece of code that helps the user in downloading mp3 files from the UIWebView. So far it has been working perfectly by detecting the last path component of the view's URL. (www.exampledownload.com/file.mp3). But in some cases the absolute URL doesn't finish in .mp3. However the UIWebView knows it is an mp3 and opens it on a MediaPlayer (As shown in the attached screenshots).

I've tested some mp3 download apps out there and they are able to detect the mp3 and download it. I want to know how to detect the file that the WebView is trying to open. The download protocol is already stablished. I just need the actual download URL of this files. I attach some screenshots to make myself more clear.

I've seen other apps in which they modify the default media player, and the webview shows the mediaplayer but with another button besides de normal playback buttons. (The download button) I would like to know also how can this be done. Thanks!

[image: Download the mp3 that is about to play]
[image: MediaPlayer presented by the UIWebView]

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the URL in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and check if its an MP3 and return NO and then do whatever you want with the file.